# Adding multiple values to the same key in Azure Table storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am looking forward to build a small non SQL database using Azure Table storage.

I have some multiple values to the same row key. Is there any way to add multiple values top the same key for example

```
PartitionKey : Qradar
RowKey : CP-WIN-08
payload : 'test1' , 'test2' , test3 ..... , testn 
log source : 'log1' , 'log2'
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just storing them as separate entities with different RowKeys and instead adding a 2nd part to the RowKey to make it unique. That 2nd part could be something natural in the data that is suitably unique, or something like a Timestamp or Guid.

e.g.

```
PK: Qradar
RowKey: CP-WIN-08_test1
Payload: 'test1'
LogSource: 'log1'

PK: Qradar
RowKey: CP-WIN-08_test2
Payload: 'test2'
LogSource: 'log2'
```

To query all rows for CP-WIN-08, you can then do a "between" query - essentially to find all the rows in the partition where the RowKey starts with "CP-WIN-08".

If there's a real reason you need to add multiple to the same RowKey, you could  just have a single property "Data" and serialize the data to a JSON string. But I'd question if there was a valid reason to do this.

Comment: thanks for the help , what is the method to to serialize the data to a JSON string

Comment: e.g. JsonConvert.SerializeObject - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_serializeobject.htm - you'd have to deserialize it on the way out too, plus you'd have to be careful you won't exceed entity size limits (1MB) or entity property size limits (64KB).

So for those reasons, I'd recommend multiple rows.

Comment: i still try to find a proper solution  is there any way to do that ?